# firebase flutter dart listen to firebase between app stop and restart

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app that gets data updates daily from firestore. It seems when listen is called on documents in firestore it only listens while the app is active. Once the app dies and is restarted it no longer listens to the firestore Is there a way to persist the listen permanently?

I've tried the workmanager but it to forgets between app stop and restart.